# How do I force Maven/Eclipse to download a JAR dependency?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, dependencies, eclipse-mars

I'm using Maven 3.3.3, Java 8 on Windows 7.  I"m using Eclipse Mars.  I'm trying to run a JUnit test in my Eclipse editor by right clicking on the class name, selecting, "Run As" -> "JUnit Test", and I'm getting this error

```
The archive: C:/Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2/commons-fileupload-1.2.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

I have this dependency in my project's pom.xml file

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

What is odd is that if I run the test directly from the command line (using bash shell on Cygwin), the test runs ...

```
$ mvn clean test -Dtest=MyControllerIT
```

Hoewver, when I look in my repository, there is no JAR file downloaded.  All it has is

```
$ ls /cygdrive/c//Users/myuser/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2/
_remote.repositories        commons-fileupload-1.2.pom.lastUpdated
commons-fileupload-1.2.pom  commons-fileupload-1.2.pom.sha1
```

How do I force the downloads of these JARs, or at least, how do I get Eclipse to stop complaining and being such a baby?

Comment: By order of how likely I think it would solve your problem (maybe all of them is needed): 1. Update the Maven project in Eclipse 2. Run Maven on the command line with the `-U` option. 3. Delete your m2 repo and run 2 then 1 again, 4. Format your drive and go home.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the POM.xml file, all you have to do is, right click and refresh the Maven Dependencies.

[image]